# Unable to destructure the localStorage Data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

How to get the data from the localStorage
I m having the data like that format
[image: localStorage]

```
{"refresh":"",
"access":"",
"id":"dbf4d515-d71e-45d9-8d5c-5efce2b217c7",
"name":"",
"email":"",
"token":""}
```

Whenever I try to get the data like this

```
const data = localStorage.getItem("userData")
console.log(data.id)
```

it shows undefined. Ihv seen multiple answers with this type of issue and tried but not able to get the data from localStorage. Anybody can highlight what I'm missing here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Store Objects in HTML5 localStorage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/how-to-store-objects-in-html5-localstorage)

Comment: The accepted answer does show how to get the value.

Comment: @atropabelladona why not? The answers explain that the returned value has to be parsed. Because the value type stored in local storage aus string.